# Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike and licences information on delivery

Tags: discussion, legal, licensing, stack-snippets, creative-commons

is it sufficient to add the *Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike* Attributions inside the source code or should it be also added inside a **separate licensing file on delivery**.

E.g. I create a project with some open source components, then I will add the different licences of the OSS components inside an own folder in my delivery CD as licensing files. So that, every customer could easily see which components under which licences are used.

In a nutshell, should the used code snippets from SO also be added inside a separate document on delivery? are there any CC A-S-A legal requirements which should be taken into account?

Comment: Ah! It was a little less than obvious at first glance that "should the used code snippets from SO also be added inside a separate document" was kind of what this was about. I seemed to have erred in closevoting. Would you be ok with making that more prominent in the question so others don't make the same mistake please?

Answer (score 1):

**Just to make sure it’s not missed:** Depending on *how* you make use of the code, your program (or parts of it) might become a derivative work. This means that your whole program (or parts of it) has to be licensed under CC BY-SA 3.0 (or a compatible license), too. Depending on the licenses of the other code you use, this might not be allowed.

**Now to your question:** As the CC BY-SA 3.0 license isn’t intended for code, it doesn’t clarify code-related aspects. The result: there is no requirement to also provide the source code if you distribute a binary.

I think the following should be a correct interpretation of the requirements:

- If you distribute a binary, but not the source code: attribute in a licensing file, and/or in the interface of the program.
- If you distribute the source code, but not a binary: attribute in a licensing file, and/or in the source code ([example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272269/193139)).
- If you distribute a binary and the source code: attribute in a licensing file (referencing both places), and/or in both places (code and interface).

Providing an unmodified copy of the code snippet would certainly be nice/useful, but that’s not required by the license.