# What happens when I use a Stack Overflow snippet without attribution

Tags: discussion, legal

What happens if I don't give attribution when I was using a code snippet in my software?

Comment: You'll burn in hell after you died.

Comment: why i don't understand

Comment: Nothing will happen until someone notices and points out your mistake. If you continue to use that snippet you'll have to add the attribution in line with what the license requires or you have to remove the snippet from your code. It is up to the license holder whether they want to be compensated / use their legal options for the period the snippet wasn't correctly attributed. Beyond cases of scrapers I have never heard of individuals or companies having to face consequences of the neglect of adding proper attribution to copy-paste plagiarism from SO.

Comment: Relevant for attribution: https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/

Comment: [This!](https://www.zdnet.com/article/the-most-copied-stackoverflow-java-code-snippet-contains-a-bug/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? *[The MIT License – Clarity on Using Code on Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-code-on-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange)*

Comment: Other questions (could be out of date): *[Is copy-pasting code from Stack Overflow an infringement to CC BY-SA 3.0 or is it considered fair use?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270014)* (2015) and *[What is up with the source code license on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25956)* (2009)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While its unlikely that the skies will part, and Jeff Atwood will descend from the heavens and smite you with a flaming yoyo - in some cases there may be consequences.

Copyleft protections - such as the CC licence in SE rely on *copyright* protections, and by ignoring the licence, you're infringing on the licence of the code snippets.

I suspect this may also have some bearing on your copyright on the code - since the code already potentially infringes on the rights of others.

The exact consequences of this may vary. Adding an attribution also means that in future - you can also look up the snippet and get more context if you don't remember where the code was from.

Comment: The lawyers of some companies can be very hot on compliance with licenses and attribution in software developed by the company (IBM certainly was when I worked for them).

Comment: Rumor has it that Jeff holds a [giant **S**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9694/282094), at least I think it's singular; he may have a few.

Comment: my reason to ask this i had a snippet in my program but i can't find in internet again. Can i add this text to credits.txt? : Some snippets authors are unknown when they found they will added in credits.txt

Comment: But then you wouldn't know where it was. Adding a link inline in a comment means at the very least, you know that snippet had to do with that page, and you can get it from a cached copy or even a datadump.